# Maximize MDIchild to MDIParent automatically on form load

Tags: c#, winforms, window, mdichild, mdiparent

I am new to WinForms and working on a parent child application. I have created a MDI parent and loading a child form inside it.

Once I select the menu in MDI parent, the child form gets loaded but not fully maximized. I have to manually maximize it to fit the MDI Parent. Below is the screenshot of what I am getting during form load.

[image: Actual result]

Every time on form load i have to maximize it. Below is the code that I am using.

```
private void newDeploymentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewDeployment nwDeploy = new NewDeployment();
        nwDeploy.MdiParent = this;
        nwDeploy.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        nwDeploy.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        nwDeploy.Show();
    }
```

I want the child form to be loaded in maximised state as shown below. I have searched google but I am getting the same code that I have used.

Is there any other way of doing this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Expected]

Comment: Try to change `WindowState` after its displayed. Maybe [FormShown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) event is ok. Consider to gather a quick [mcve], then someone may *play* with it or see problems.

Comment: `nwDeploy.Show(); nwDeploy.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`. Remove `nwDeploy.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`.

Comment: why dock an MDI child form ? There is no sense in that. It would even block other MDI Child forms from appearing on the main form. Just set the WindowState to Maximized. However, if you have a MDI Child open, and you resize it (so its not maximized) then all new created MDI child forms will also not be maximized. That is how MDI works, its normal behaviour

Comment: @GuidoG. They will be working on only one form at a time. hence I am docking it. also the content is heavy.

Comment: If the users can only have one form at a time, then why use MDI ?

Comment: But still, MDI Children should not be docked, MDI is taking care of that already for you.

Comment: @GuidoG. The application has 10 modules which will be drived by choosing the menu's. hence have used the MDIChild

Comment: But still, you dont need to dock the MDI Child. You want to force it to fill the main window, but MDI tries to do the same or tries to not maximize it. You are fighting the MDI in your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi and Sinatr, I have modified the code by loading the form then modify its window state to maximized.

Below is my updated code

```
 NewDeployment nwDeploy = new NewDeployment();
            nwDeploy.MdiParent = this;
            nwDeploy.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            nwDeploy.Show();
            nwDeploy.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set the child form's WindowState to Maximized from within its own Load event.  Works every time.